# Type 'HTMLFormControlsCollection' has no property 'x' and no string index signature

Tags: typescript, index-signature, typescript-lib-dom

The following error appears when trying to destructure a `form.elements` object:

> Type 'HTMLFormControlsCollection' has no property 'x' and no string index signature

```
// in a class

domRefs: {[key: string]: HTMLFormElement | null} = {
  myForm: null
}

onButtonClick = () => {
  console.debug(this.domRefs.myForm!.elements) // screenshot below
  const {a, b, c} = this.domRefs.myForm!.elements
}
```

[image: screenshot of the console output]

I don't want to use the `: any` type annotation that does not emit this error.

Comment: I am sure you already solved it long time ago - but just for the benefit of other readers - as usual, the culprit is a limitation of the standard definition library, nothing else one can do apart from augmenting the `HTMLFormControlsCollection` interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the standard DOM definitions library (and still is in 2021). Here is how the `HTMLFormControlsCollection` is defined in it - notice the lack of a string index signature (this is exactly why the error happens):

```ts
interface HTMLFormControlsCollection extends HTMLCollectionBase {
    /**
     * Returns the item with ID or name name from the collection.
     * 
     * If there are multiple matching items, then a RadioNodeList object containing all those elements is returned.
     */
    namedItem(name: string): RadioNodeList | Element | null;
}
```

Its parent interface `HTMLCollectionBase` also lacks a string index signature (despite having a number index signature):

```ts
interface HTMLCollectionBase {
    /**
     * Sets or retrieves the number of objects in a collection.
     */
    readonly length: number;
    /**
     * Retrieves an object from various collections.
     */
    item(index: number): Element | null;
    [index: number]: Element;
}
```

However, `HTMLFormControlsCollection` should have a string index signature by definition (see [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlformcontrolscollection)):

> element = collection[name]
>
> radioNodeList = collection[name]
>
> Returns the item with ID or name name from the collection.

So, with the help of some declaration merging, we can fix the omission:

```ts
interface HTMLFormControlsCollection extends HTMLCollectionBase {
  [item: string]: Element | RadioNodeList;
}
```

Comment: This gives me `Property 'item' of type '(index: number) => Element | null' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Element | RadioNodeList'.` in TS 4.7. Is there any newer approach?

Comment: @JakubKotrs can you share a reproducible example from the Playground, if possible?

Comment: No, it works here, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIBUCyAZAYgeygFsBhfcKfAGwGcyqqIExhzkIAPSEAExrSzZ6jZqxAAhODRQBvAFDJkAbWCQiALmQ0wUUAHMAupoCijIhHDIAPsgBKcHqwBy+HhGzBtAbjkBfIA, but as soon as I copy to VSCode, it's all red with TS 4.7.2 :(

Comment: @JakubKotrs hmm, strange. Can you share the tsconfig file of the project where this happens? I can try a loxal install of 4.7.2 and see for myself if it errors out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you're putting into this, I appreciate it a lot! Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/Goues/1174583df3550d92ee0c8195e082c28c

Comment: I see same error as @JakubKotrs in VSCode..

Answer (score 0):

As described by @oleg-valter-is-with-ukraine,

```
interface HTMLFormControlsCollection extends HTMLCollectionBase {
  [item: string]: HTMLInputElement | RadioNodeList;
}
```

It worked for me I just changed the Element to `HTMLInputElement` in the `lib.dom.d.ts` file

Comment: You should not be changing anything in `node_modules`. This change is only for you and not persistent. This means, whenever you or somebody else (re)installs your repo, those changes would get overwritten. Changing something in `node_modules` is good for testing. You can then make [type overrides _(link)_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032655/985454) in your [`global.d.ts` _(link)_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73389225/985454) files inside your `src` project folder or you can make PR in the 3rd party repo.

Comment: @Qwerty, thankyou I will keep that in my mind and will rectify the mistake