# How can I refer to an existing type from another module in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Supposed I am writing a Node.js hello world server. Then as the callback to the `http.createServer` function I have a function that basically looks like this:

```
(req, res) => {
  // ...
}
```

Now, if I want to do this in TypeScript I would like to tell the compiler that `req` and `res` are the appropriate objects from Node.js. How do I add these as types? Basically this has to look like this:

```
(req: X, res: Y): void => {
  // ...
}
```

But what do I have to provide for `X` and `Y`? I don't want to recreate everything from scratch, and I suppose there has to be some mechanism to refer to an existing type, hasn't it?

I suppose that the types for `req` and `res` have already been defined somewhere, e.g. in `@types/node`. How do I use one of those types defined there in my own code?

Comment: You wan't to use same typing at lots of places ? if yes this is [`possible duplicate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984889/global-types-in-typescript)

Comment: I think you might be looking for the `typeof` Typescript operator

Comment: I suppose that the types for `req` and `res` have already been defined, e.g. in `@types/node`. How do I use one of those types defined there in my own code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `http.d.ts`, `RequestListener` type is declared.

```ts
type RequestListener = (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => void;
```

You can import those types from `http` module.

```ts
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';

const requestListener = (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse): void => {
}
```