# Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations(2669)

Tags: node.js, typescript, global

I would like to store my NodeJS config in the global scope.

I tried to follow this => [Extending TypeScript Global object in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074713/extending-typescript-global-object-in-node-js) and other solution on stackoverflow,

I made a file called global.d.ts where I have the following code

```
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
      interface Global {
          config: MyConfigType
      }
    }
  }
```

> Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in
>   external modules or ambient module declarations.ts(2669)

but doing this works fine =>

```
declare module NodeJS  {
    interface Global {
        config: MyConfigType
    }
}
```

the problem is, I need to import the file `MyConfigType` to type the config, but the second option do not allow that.

Comment: Understand that an "external module" is a file containing an `import` or `export` statement, that an "ambient module declaration" reads `declare module "m" {}` (note the quotes), and reread the error message.

Comment: You might need `export {}`

Comment: In an ambient decl. file that's not been turned into a module you are already operating in the global scope (outside of declare module {} braces) so you can just omit declare global

Answer (score 437, accepted):

You can indicate that the file is a module like so:

```js
export {};

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            config: MyConfigType
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, works!  What trickery is this "export {};".  Can you provide some information that I can read up on as to why that works?

Comment: I think the trick is just that an "external module" is a file containing an import or export statement, so this makes it an "external module". It does seem a little strange that this is needed though...

Comment: @user1949561 here's a good explanation of why https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257742/1048847

Comment: I think that declaring `MyConfigType` in another file and then using `import` should fix the issue too. (if this option is applicable to your case)

Answer (score 47):

Or if you're trying to add a global type within the browser context:

```js
export {};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ENV: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Just tried this but every time I close the .d.ts file the variable that's on the window is underlined in red as an error. The error goes away when I open the window.

Comment: @LJD try adding the file to tsconfig.json: `"include": ["globals.d.ts"]`

Answer (score 18):

If your `.d.ts` is executing as a "script" (it has no `import/export` statements), you won't need to `declare global` at all, and can simply remove it. A "script" is already executing in the global context.

(aside: this is why adding `export {}` works, it turns it from a "script" into a "module" and your declarations in the `.d.ts` are no longer global by default)

With an example modifying `console`:

Before:

```typescript
declare global {
  interface Console {
    log2: (...args: any[])=>void;
  }
}
```

After:

```typescript
// This will be global!
interface Console {
  log2: (...args: any[])=>void;
}
```

Thanks to @okcoker and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257742/2759427 for the explanation of .d.ts contexts

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I am using TypeScript within a browser app, with .js scripts loaded via <script> tags in index.js. This works perfectly for my use case.