# Typescript: .d.ts file not recognized

Tags: typescript

This one's probably extremely simple but I'm going nuts trying to figure it out.

I have a very simple self-executing function in an outer index.ts file that needs to register a global variable on the window object. I want to assign it like so:

```
(() => {
  window.myCustomGlobal = new MyCustomGlobal();
})()
```

I created index.d.ts alongside index.ts:

```
import { MyCustomGlobal} from './classes';

declare interface Window {
  myCustomGlobal: MyCustomGlobal;
}
```

No errors in the above, all looks good. The application compiles fine.

In the IDE, however, I get an error:
`ts2339: Property 'myCustomGlobal' does not exist on type 'Window'`

I can't for the life of me figure out what exactly makes Typescript "figure out" what .d.ts file to include. In certain libs, having a .d.ts file alongside a .js file causes it to get picked up, and it works fine. In fact, I used the *exact same interface as above* with a global third-party lib and it worked great; it just seems like my IDE won't pick it up.

I've tried adding `index.d.ts` to tsconfig.json in `include` as well as `files` with no luck.

Can somebody explain, as if to a child, what causes TS to pick up declaration files? Some days I feel like I get it, and then in stupid simple examples like this I feel like an idiot.

Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There might be two issues here:

1.) You need to augment `Window` interface in *global* scope.

Either remove all `import`/`export` keywords to make the containing file a non-module/script. Or you can use `declare global` in a module to mark everything wrapped in it as global declaration:

```
import { MyCustomGlobal} from './classes';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    myCustomGlobal: MyCustomGlobal;
  }
}
```

2.) Equally named files, that only differ in their `.ts`/`.d.ts` extension, [don't work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7624#issuecomment-202501572). To quote the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details):

> Please note that the compiler does not include files that can be possible outputs; e.g. if the input includes index.ts, then index.d.ts and index.js are excluded. In general, having files that differ only in extension next to each other is not recommended.

Make sure to give a different name to `index.d.ts` (like `global.d.ts`), so the compiler doesn't only pick `index.ts`. `global.d.ts` will included automatically, if placed somewhere in the TS project marked by `tsconfig.json` and
if `"files"` and `"include"` config options are left unspecified.

Comment: That was it -- it was the file name. What a way to waste a couple hours trying to figure this out. I had tried the declare global syntax and it wasn't working, but only because of the file name. 
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: but what I can do if I want to write d.ts file by hand to some .js file?

Comment: @perymimon Not sure, what you mean. Can you give an example? The precedence order for types is `.ts > .d.ts > .js`. So, given equally named `index.d.ts` and `index.js` file, types are taken from former as desired.

Comment: I try to write `.d.ts` file for `.js` file that already exist.  and I want vscode or typescript recognize the definition so when I hover over the function I will see the definition as in the `d.ts` file

Comment: @perymimon [Module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) should resolve that case automatically, if the `.d.ts` file has the same path/name as the `.js` one. This resolution works even in the project, if you don't have a `tsconfig.json` (just tried it). Above behavior is  different for global types (not `import`ed files) - in this case, tsconfig.json exclude rules also play a role. I suggest to open a new question, as this seems to be non-standard behavior.

Comment: I encountered similar issue but still doesn't work. ;_:
And adding `declare global {...}` will cause `Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.ts(2669)
` which noted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132428/augmentations-for-the-global-scope-can-only-be-directly-nested-in-external-modul

Comment: @kuanyui you only need `declare global` in a module (file with `import`/`export`). For a script file you can simply omit this.

Comment: "So make sure to rename index.d.ts to something like global.d.ts" is what fixed it for me!

Comment: Btw: the docs link content has changed and does not include quoted passage  anymore. I'll leave it here anyway, as it's imo still a precise description.

Comment: Part 2 was absolutely the ticket, thank you

Comment: The second part was helpful. I named my definition file `index.d.ts` and spent one-hour checking if my config was correct. You saved my day!

Comment: I added the `.d.ts` to tsconfig's `"files"`, and now it is included globally, even if I have a `.ts` file with the same name.

Answer (score 23):

We declared `"include": ["src"]` in our `tsconfig.json` and this caused `declarations.d.ts` in root (`"/"`) to not be detected.

Comment: thanks. after I included inside "include" it started to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is just so weird, but, In order for it to work I needed to include the types folder in the `include` secion in the `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score -1):

On my end. I have to add `DOM` under `lib` in tsconfig.json so typescript compiler recognized `window` object.