# Failed to extend node.js global with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to extend the `global` in node.js, using typescript.

For this, I've created the following structure:
[image]

File content of `index.d.ts`:

```
import socketio from 'socket.io';

declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        sockets: socketio.Socket[];
    }
}
```

In my tsconfig.json file I provided: `"typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types", "./@types"]`

But I still can't use `global.sockets`. How to fix it?

**Please note that** if I would write `index.d.ts` as:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        sockets: any[];
    }
}
```

Then I would be able to access `global.sockets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this stackoverflow question: [Ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132428/augmentations-for-the-global-scope-can-only-be-directly-nested-in-external-modul)

Turns out that adding `export {}` and `declare global` would do the work.

So the final file would be:

```
export {};

import socketio from 'socket.io';

declare global {
    declare namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            sockets: socketio.Socket[];
        }
    }
}
```