# `tsc` cannot find self-defined declaration files (.d.ts)

Tags: typescript, tsc

## 0. Prequisitions

- `typescript@4.3.4`
- Editor: VSCode 1.15.7
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04

> ➡➡➡ [Minimalist reproduce repo in here](https://github.com/kuanyui/question_tsc_dts)

## 1. Project Structure

I create a minimalist TypeScript project whose structure looks like this:

```js
.  // Project root directory ($PWD)
├── dist
│   └── main.js  // output file
├── Makefile
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── types
│       └── window.d.ts  // ←extends some properties to `global.Window` 
└── tsconfig.json
```

## 2. Customize Interface `global.Window`

I extends some customized properties attached on built-in `Window` global interface:

```typescript
// window.d.ts
export { }  // to solve TS2669, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132428/augmentations-for-the-global-scope-can-only-be-directly-nested-in-external-modul

declare global {
  interface OurDefinedGlobalRuntimeEnv {
    /** Runtime value (Defined in preload.js)
    *   - `web`: Ordinary web browser.
    *   - `electron`: Electron renderer window.
    */
    BROWSER: 'electron' | 'web' | undefined
    SERVER_IP: string
    DEBUG: string
    NODE_ENV: node_env_t,
  }
  type node_env_t = 'production' | 'development'
  interface Window {
    __RUNTIME_ENV__: OurDefinedGlobalRuntimeEnv
  }
}
```

Then inject our self-defined object into `window`:

```ts
// main.ts
type inferPropType<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K]
const rtenv1: inferPropType<Window, '__RUNTIME_ENV__'> = {
  BROWSER: 'electron',
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'development' : 'production',
  SERVER_IP: process.env.SERVER_IP || '',
  DEBUG: process.env.DEBUG || '',
  ENV_VAR: process.env,
}
const rtenv2: OurDefinedGlobalRuntimeEnv = rtenv1
window.__RUNTIME_ENV__ = rtenv1
```

## 3. VSCode IntelliSense & `tsc`

So far, VSCode's IntelliSense doesn't output any error or warning, and type can be inferred by IntelliSense correctly:
[image: VSCode can infer types defined in d.ts correctly]

And run `tsc` with the root path of the project as `$CWD`:

```bash
cd PROJECT_ROOT_DIR
npx tsc --outDir ./dist/ --module commonjs ./src/*.ts
```

However, this will explode:
[image: Error output by tsc]

## 4. Where The Problem Is?

After debugging for > 7 hours, I found `tsc` cannot detect `*.d.ts` when the file want to be compiled and `*.d.ts` are not ***in the same folder***. That is to say, if move `window.d.ts`:

```js
.
└── src
    ├── main.ts
    └── types
        └── window.d.ts
```

become this:

```js
.
└── src
    ├── main.ts
    └── window.d.ts
```

Now `tsc` compilation passed:

```bash
npx tsc --outDir ./dist/ --module commonjs ./src/*.ts
```

## 5. Questions

1. In TypeScript official document, it seems own-defined `*.d.ts` can be placed in any sub folder of the project?
2. VSCode's IntelliSense can correctly load and infer the types defined in our `*.d.ts` and the extended global `Window` interface, so I guess I didn't wrote the definition file wrongly...right?

> The types defined in our `window.d.ts` will be used by multiple entry files, in this case I should not copy this `window.d.ts` to multiple folders.
>
> *(NOTE: This is merely a minimalist project to reproduce the issue, so I only wrote one entry file `main.ts`. In real world, this is actually a large Electron project which contains other entries files like `preload.js` and `electron_entry.js` and a SPA entry bundled by Webpack...etc)*

3. Does `tsc --outDir OUT_DIR SRC_FILE` always ignores `${PWD}/tsconfig.json` unless I use `tsc --project ./tsconfig.json` or just `tsc` (will compile everything according to `tsconfig.json`)? I wonder know if I can just build **on specific `.ts` file via `tsc XXXX...` directly ** WITHOUT create multiple `tsconfig.json` nor via `webpack`.
4. Although I found use `tsc` (without any parameters) can compile successfully (it loads `tsconfig.json` implicitly), but I don't know how it succeeded nor which option in `tsconfig.json` made it successful... Even with params `--baseUrl . --rootDir . --moduleResolution Node --module commonjs` still cannot load `window.d.ts`.
   `

Answer (score 2):

since it is not referenced anywhere under the root path, the compiler is not aware of the existence of the global declaration file so you need to pass its path in addition to the root path (tsc gets set of TypeScript files)

so in your scenario, following would work:

`npx tsc --outDir ./dist/ --module commonjs ./src/*.ts ./src/types/window.d.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

The command your are running : `npx tsc --outDir ./dist/ --module commonjs ./src/*.ts` is wrong. Here you are asking TypeScript to *only compile files under `src/*.ts`.

## Fix

Compile with tsconfig i.e. `npx tsc -p ./tsconfig.json`. Or even `npx tsc` as it will pickup tsconfig.json by default

PS I tested your project, its fine [image]

Comment: Sorry, I've mentioned this way in my original question but it's not what I want (because I have 3 entry files in real world... So hard to explain, I totally cannot understand the behavior of `tsc`....).  

At last, I finally give up and wrote a `webpack.config.js` contains multiple entries to build my project, now problem seems solved...