# Nuxt and TypeScript: window.__NUXT__

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt project with TypeScript and need to access `window.__NUXT__` because I want to [load Algolia on SSR](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/server-side-rendering/vue/#with-nuxt).

```
beforeMount() {
  const results =
    (this.$nuxt.context && this.$nuxt.context.nuxtState.algoliaState) ||
    window.__NUXT__.algoliaState

  this.instantsearch.hydrate(results)

  // Remove the SSR state so it can't be applied again by mistake
  delete this.$nuxt.context.nuxtState.algoliaState
  delete window.__NUXT__.algoliaState
},
```

TypeScript is complaining:

```
Property '__NUXT__' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

Is there a way to tell TypeScript about `__NUXT__`?

Answer (score 0):

You can augment the `global.Window` type with the `__NUXT__` property:

1. Create `<projectRoot>/global.d.ts` with these contents:

   ```js
   // https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499895/6277151
   export {}

   declare global {
     interface Window {
       __NUXT__: any
     }
   }
   ```
2. If using VS Code, restart the IDE to properly index the `.d.ts` file.