# Object name not found in Typescript but is in Javascript

Tags: typescript, object, syntax

I am using config-webpack to manage configuration settings in my application.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/config-webpack

This takes all the configs in a JSON file and makes them available in the application as a JS object - i.e. CONFIG.SOMEBOOLEANSETTNIG

In my project, if I have a .js file this works fine and the following statement resolves;

`if (CONFIG.SOMEBOOLEANSETTNIG==true) {         ...     }`

However, the same code in a .ts or .tsx file displays an error with the CONFIG underlined with "Cannot find name 'CONFIG' ts(2304)" and the compilation fails.

I feel that I am missing something really simple but I am new to TS!  Thanks.

I've tried looking into Typescript syntax documentation but I can't see where I am going wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider declaring `CONFIG` as a global namespace for your local typescript.

Should look something like this:

```js
import ConfigWebpackPlugin from 'config-webpack';

export default declare global {
  CONFIG: ConfigWebpackPlugin
}
```

**NOTE:** If you don't have a global type file you can make a custom one and add it to the `typeRoots` array in your `tsconfig.json` file.

```js
"typeRoots": ["path/to/custom-type.d.ts" ]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried the suggestion but get "Cannot find name 'declare'" and under global get "';' expected" and "error TS2670: Augmentations for the global scope should have 'declare' modifier unless they appear in already ambient context."

Comment: @Jaycee26 What happens when you try installing the types for this package by running `npm install -D @types/config-webpack`?

Comment: I did try that and '@types/config-webpack is not in this registry'

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499895/5589405)