# Overriding Cypress typescript using declaration file

Tags: typescript, cypress, typescript-namespace

I was reading this [article](https://filiphric.com/working-with-api-response-data-in-cypress) about Cypress. On the last part, the author overrode the types to be inferred by typescript when calling `Cypress.env`.

Here's the snippet that i want to understand.

```
export { };

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {

    export interface Cypress {

      /**
       * Returns all environment variables set with CYPRESS_ prefix or in "env" object in "cypress.json"
       *
       * @see https://on.cypress.io/env
       */
      env(): Partial<EnvKeys>;
      /**
       * Returns specific environment variable or undefined
       * @see https://on.cypress.io/env
       * @example
       *    // cypress.json
       *    { "env": { "foo": "bar" } }
       *    Cypress.env("foo") // => bar
       */
      env<T extends keyof EnvKeys>(key: T): EnvKeys[T];
      /**
       * Set value for a variable.
       * Any value you change will be permanently changed for the remainder of your tests.
       * @see https://on.cypress.io/env
       * @example
       *    Cypress.env("host", "http://server.dev.local")
       */
      env<T extends keyof EnvKeys>(key: T, value: EnvKeys[T]): void;

      /**
       * Set values for multiple variables at once. Values are merged with existing values.
       * @see https://on.cypress.io/env
       * @example
       *    Cypress.env({ host: "http://server.dev.local", foo: "foo" })
       */
      env(object: Partial<EnvKeys>): void;

    }

  }
}

interface EnvKeys {
  'boards': Array<{
    created: string;
    id: number;
    name: string;
    starred: boolean;
    user: number;
  }>;
  'lists': Array<{
    boardId: number
    title: string
    id: number
    created: string
  }>;
}
```

Few questions that I have in this snippet:

1. How does typescript know about this file when it is named as `env.d.ts`? I know that typescript automatically know the types if the file is named the same with the file (e.g `command.ts` -> `command.d.ts`
2. What's the use of `export {}` here. If i comment this one out, Vscode complains.
3. Why do we have to add `declare global` here when the original Cypress typescript starts with `declare namespace Cypress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in typescript, but here's my take

**1. How does typescript know about this file when it is named as env.d.ts**

In `tsconfig.json` you have

```js
include": [
  "**/*.ts"
]
```

which means `env.d.ts` is included in the compile.

Run `tsc --listFiles --noEmit` to see what get's included.

---

**2. What's the use of export {} here**

You are merging namespaces, and the docs [Merging Namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces) say

> To merge the namespaces, type definitions from **exported** interfaces declared in each namespace are themselves merged.

Further

> Non-exported members are only visible in the original (un-merged) namespace. This means that after merging, merged members that came from other declarations cannot see non-exported members.

So, it's information hiding - like public vs private variables.

**Oops wrong anwser**

I just realized you want to know about the first line.

Please see this answer
[Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations(2669)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499895/16997707)

> I think the trick is just that an "external module" is a file containing an import or export statement, so this makes it an "external module".

---

**3. Why do we have to add declare global**

Ref [Global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

> You can also add declarations to the global scope from inside a module

When you write a test, you can use `Cypress.Commands.add()`, `cy.get()`, `it()`, etc without needing to import anything because they are declared globally.

To merge with the global Cypress interface, your enhancement must also be declared as global.

To see the effect, change `env.d.ts`

```js
declare module "env" {  
  namespace Cypress {
```

and `addTaskApi.ts`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('addTaskApi', ({ title, boardIndex = 0, listIndex = 0 }) => {
  cy.request('POST', '/api/tasks', {
      title,
      boardId: Cypress.env('boards')[boardIndex].id,
      listId: Cypress.env('lists')[listIndex].id
    })
    .then(({ body }) => {

      const tasks = Cypress.env('tasks')  // tasks typed as any 
                                          // instead of  'tasks': Array<{ boardId:...number;
      tasks.push(body);
    })
})
```

Comment: Awesome. There's a lot to unpack here. I'll be learning a lot of stuff here. Thanks a lot