# How do Typescript interface scope is working ? How to make interfaces global?

Tags: typescript, deno

I'm a new user of Typescript and Deno and I don't really understand how the interfaces scope are working.

**I have a tree layer application :**

The first layer (**App.ts**) is my application, this is where the core logic part of my application is. This part can be any file that need to refer to the second layer (API.ts).

The second layer (**API.ts**) is the entry point where I can communicate with any distant API (like Facebook, stripe, Google API)

The third layer is a bunch of .ts file. The second layer (API.ts) can communicate with each of them. Every file handles a very precise part of a particular API. I have for example one **FB_page.ts** to handle the part of the Facebook API responsible for pages, another file **STRP_Subscription** that handle the part of the Stripe API responsible for subscriptions, etc.

My problem is

I have a lot of interfaces to handle every type of parameter, every error and every response an API call can input or output. And I need these interfaces in every layer of my application.

It would be very cool if I can put interfaces of a particular API part inside the file that is responsible for it. For example, if I need several interfaces for the Facebook page API, I would like to put then inside the **FB_page.ts** file.

But it's tedious to have to import the **FB_page.ts** file if I need them in the first layer of my application **App.ts** like this : 
`import {IPost, IPost_Error, IPost_Response} from '../lib/FB_page.ts';`

So I put them inside .d.ts files, but they seem not to be global either ?

How can I have access to my interfaces without having to import them everywhere in my application ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984889/global-types-in-typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost everything in Deno is a module. If you provide a non-module/script with global types, it won't be found. Also, Deno cannot deal with `.d.ts` file extension, except for a few places with [compiler hints](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/typescript#compiler-hint).

#### What you can do

1. Rename the files containing the interfaces to `.ts`.
2. Put global types in a module (file with `import`/`export`)
3. Make sure to import this module, so Deno CLI can find it when compiling

Note, that  `deno` uses its own integrated TS compiler different from the one of your IDE (VS Code and others). So an IDE showing no type error doesn't mean, that `deno run` or `deno cache` can compile sources.

#### Example code

```
// Put following code inside one of your used modules
declare global {
  interface IPost {
    foo: string;
  }
}

// IPost will be available globally without import
const post: IPost = { foo: "bar" }
```

If you want to separate the global types from your other code, you could use a side-effect import:

```
import "./lib/global.ts";
const post: IPost = { foo: "bar" };
```

global.ts:

```
export {}; // use some export to mark file as module
declare global {
  interface IPost {
    foo: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting namespaces

```
export as namespace ICalendar;
import { Document } from "mongoose";

export interface Calendar extends Document {
userId?: Object
}
```