# How to add a new property to NextRequest types?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm creating a middleware that adds a "name" property to NextRequest, this property will be used in other parts of the API

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    req.name = 'Foo'

    NextResponse.next()
}
```

I get this error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'NextRequest'`

An alternative would be to create an interface that extends NextRequest, but I would have to import all files that want to access the "name" property

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

interface CustomRequest extends NextRequest {
    name: string
}

export function middleware(req: CustomRequest) {
    req.name = 'Foo'

    NextResponse.next()
}
```

Is there any way to add this property into NextRequest global types?

Comment: Make `CustomRequest` a global type. See [Global types in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984889/global-types-in-typescript).

Comment: @juliomalves I checked it again and it worked, thanks

Comment: Hey, could you please post an answer and example code of how you got this to work? I am stuck. Also, are you modifying the req object in the [middleware.ts](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) file or a custom middleware file?

Comment: @YulePale Sorry for the delay, I created an answer showing the step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Showing how I solved the problem based on the comment from [juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172177/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-nextrequest-types#comment124051104_70172177)*

---

Create a .d.ts file, you can use any name

```
// global.d.ts
import { NextRequest as OriginalNextRequest } from 'next/server'

declare global {
    declare interface NextRequest extends OriginalNextRequest {
        name: string
    }
}
```

**It is necessary:**

- `extends OriginalNextRequest` to show all `NextRequest` types of next
- Rename the `NextRequest` import, otherwise when extending the `NextRequest` the typescript will think that `NextRequest` is the interface you are creating and will only show the `name` in the autocomplete

To import the modified `NextRequest`

```
// tsconfig.json

"paths": {
    "*": ["*.d.ts"]
}
```

If the .d.ts file is in a folder

```
"paths": {
    "*": ["types/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Now the typescript doesn't show the error saying `name` doesn't exist in `NextRequest`

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    req.name = 'Foo'

    NextResponse.next()
}
```

**NOTE:** Do not import `NextRequest` from next, otherwise the global type will be replaced by `NextRequest` from import

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    req.name = 'Foo' // error

    NextResponse.next()
}
```

If you want to use `NextRequest` from next, rename the import