# How to modify the request object in Next.js middleware file?

Tags: next.js, request, httprequest, middleware, request-object

How can I modify the request object in Next.js [middleware file](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware)?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172177/how-to-add-a-new-property-to-nextrequest-types) but it does not answer my question.

I have a middleware file that looks like below:

```
// middleware.js    
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    req.name = "foo";
    //If I console.log req.name I see it is equal to foo.
    console.log(req.name) // logs "foo"
}
```

Then I have an api route like below

```
// pages/api/hello.js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    console.log( req.name ) //logs undefined
    // what can I do so that I can access the new properties
    // I put in the req object in the middlware file here?
}
```

Comment: haha, all my googled questions lead me to your questions here on Stackoverflow. I think we have the same problem. I wanted to find a way how to add `app.use` in the other question now i found this one where you asked the same thing i thought it would work. So, while we cant use `app.use` in Nextjs i thought there must be a way to modify the `req` object. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I did not find a way :). I just used next-connect.

Answer (score 1):

As of NextJs v 13.0.0 there is a workaround setting headers
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware

```
//middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware (req, res) {
  // NextJs doesn't allow you to modify the request object. So the only way to pass the data to the client is to add it to the headers of a new request.
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers)
  requestHeaders.set('xname', "foo")

  // And the middleware expects a response object as a return so we need to involve that as well.
  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      // New request headers
      headers: requestHeaders
    }
  })

  return response
}
```

In the api you can access the header

```
// pages/api/hello.js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const nameHeader = req.headers.xname
    console.log('Hello '. nameHeader) // Hello foo
}
```

You can also set the header to a JSON object if you want to pass more data this way, but Id recommend being a bit restrictive to keep the size of the header down and avoiding 431 errors 'Request header fields too large'